# The use of ANOVA for small sample sizes with prior knowledge of the population

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I want to compare the response from three levels of one factor. I do lengthy and fairly expensive experiments, and cannot increase my sample size (often 3 measurement replicates on the same solution under different conditions).

[image]

My first thought was to use one-way ANOVA, but checking for ANOVAs assumptions (normal sample distribution and equal variance), I found that my data doesn't really support its use.

However, because of prior knowledge of the process that produces these samples, I know their population distributions should be normal, and their variance equal. Can I therefore use ANOVA (and t-tests for that matter), despite my sample indicating otherwise? Or would it be better to use a non-parametric test?

Comment: checking normality assumptions with only 9 observation is a a bit dangerous due to low power.

Comment: I agree. I expect it to be normal if my sample size was larger, which is what made me think of the possibility of simply assuming normality, and going ahead with ANOVA.